# Как добавить к текущему Url get параметр

Tags: php

Как добавить к текущему Url get  параметр .Например если я нахожусь на странице /service/ у меня к урлу добавлялся ?you.В итоге адрес был бы такой site.ru/service/?you

Answer (score 1):

Добавляет к текущему адресу GET, Даже если уже есть другие GET параметры

```
// Merge $_GET with new parameter
$QS = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, ["page"=>2]));
```

Теперь можно например выводит в пагинации:

```
// You should apply htmlspecialchars() on the path prior outputting:
echo "<a href='" . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?$QS") . "'> $i 
</a>";
```

Если нужна переадресация, то не выводите, а отправляйте в заголовок:

```
 header('Location: ' . htmlspecialchars("$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?$QS"));
```

Comment: Мне кажется что htmlspecialchars в Location лишняя.

Answer (score 0):

У AlexandrX в функции strpos строка урл ищется в строке "?". Нужно наоборот:
`$delimeter = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') === FALSE ? '?' : '&';`

Answer (score -1):

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?you');
```

Comment: ок,а если гет эже существует то как добавить к нему ещё один?

Comment: @J.Doe точно так же

Comment: т.е проверка на & не нужна?

Comment: ну если хотите прям по-феншую, то можете заморочиться вот так: 
`$delimeter = strpos('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === FALSE ? '?' : '&';
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$delimeter.'you');`

Comment: да тьфу ты, не смог в каменте код с новой строки начать -))

Comment: @AlexandrX даже строка говорит "редактируй ответ" ))